Hibernate search outbound polling not creating its tables
we want to implement Hibernate search outbox polling in our project to synchronize indexes among multiple nodes. The project is structured in multiple modules, as follows:

main module

dao layer
service layer
rest layer
spring config



As the official documentation instructs, I simply added a line to spring config module application.properties file:
hibernate.search.coordination.strategy = outbox-polling

This, however, did nothing. No HSEARCH tables were created and there is no mention of outbox polling anywhere in the startup logs. I then tried to add the tables manually, using a Flyway migration:
/* Table created to mirror org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.outboxpolling.event.impl.OutboxEvent */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "HSEARCH_OUTBOX_EVENT" CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE "HSEARCH_OUTBOX_EVENT"
(
    id                  uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    "entityName"        varchar,
    "entityId"          varchar,
    "entityIdHash"      bigint,
    "payload"           bytea,
    "retries"           bigint DEFAULT 0,
    "processAfter"      timestamp,
    "status"            varchar,
    "tenantId"          varchar
);

ALTER TABLE "HSEARCH_OUTBOX_EVENT" ADD CONSTRAINT pk_hsearch_outbox_event PRIMARY KEY (id);

/* Table created to mirror org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.outboxpolling.cluster.impl.Agent */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "HSEARCH_AGENT" CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE "HSEARCH_AGENT"
(
    id                  uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    "type"              varchar,
    "name"              varchar,
    "expiration"        timestamp,
    "state"             varchar,
    "totalShardCount"   bigint,
    "assignedShardIndex"   bigint,
    "payload"           bytea,
    "tenantId"              varchar
);

ALTER TABLE "HSEARCH_AGENT" ADD CONSTRAINT pk_hsearch_agent PRIMARY KEY (id);

Tables were created, but Hibernate search does not pick them up and upon a creation/update of an indexed entity, no rows are inserted to either of the tables. The documentation on this topic is very sparse, and I am now stuck. What's preventing Hibernate search from either automatically creating the schema, or accepting my manually created tables? Does it have to do with the structure of our project?
We're using PG 16, Spring boot 3.0.1, Hibernate search 6.1.8.Final and Hibernate search polling 7.1.1.Final.

Have you added the required dependency?
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm-outbox-polling</artifactId>
   <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

If you are not relying on Hibernate ORM’s automatic schema generation, then the outbox polling tables won't be created and you'll need to do so through a script as you've mentioned in the question.
Also, there's plenty of documentation on the outbox polling coordination if you check the corresponding section.
Then... because you are using Spring, see this section any Hibernate Search properties have to be prefixed with spring.jpa.properties. when you are using the ORM mapper.

You pointed me in the right direction, I updated everything to the latest version and now at least, the tables are generated and populated. A new problem has occurred - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'Lucene87' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene99]
However, the most recent hibernate search does not use that Lucene versio and I can't figure out what is causing this.

Does your app point to an index created by a previous version Lucene? If so - you'd need to recreate an index. Also, check your dependencies, e.g. run mvn dependency:tree and see whether anything is pulling an older version of Lucene.

mvn dependency:tree shows nothing unusual, everything is on version 9.9.X. As for the index rebuild, I develop it locally with an empty DB everytime I start my app on localhost, there should be no index to rebuild.
